# Sound indicator broken

Tags: sound, indicator, mate, spotify

I was playing music on Spotify and realized everytime I change the volume on the app, the sound indicator (on the panel) stops working. It doesn't change my volume when I slide the indicator. I'm on Ubuntu-Mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotfy for Linux is actually unmaintained, so it may be a very long time till it gets fixed:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/spotify-linux-no-development

In particular:

> Spotify’s rep also says the company do ‘want to fix’ some minor issues, like incorrect MPRIS data being passed to sound applets in GNOME, Unity, Cinnamon, etc, but when this may happen is as-yet unknown.